# What is the best way to copy the lower resolution mips of a texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

The OpenGL application I maintain has tu run in systems with small VRAM.

In some cases, at runtime, I can guarantee that a specific texture won't need high resolution. My textures are in compressed format.

What I would like to do is to discard the highest resolution mips to save VRAM.

[image]

I thought of doing something like this psudocode:

```
u32 fullResTex = loadTextureAndUploadToGPU("my_texture.ktx");
generateMipmaps(fullResTex);

u32 lowResTex = createTexture();
copyMipsLowestMips(fullResTex -> lowResMips);

destroy(fullResTex)
```

I'm not sure which function of the OpenGL API can help me with "copyMipsLowestMips".
I have found a few that could potentially serve the purpose: [glCopyTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyTexImage2D.xhtml),
[glCopyImageSubData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyImageSubData.xhtml).

I have seen that `glCopyImageSubData` requires OpenGL 4.3 though. I would prefer to avoid using versions later than 3.3 but I might be able to use the function if available through an extension.

What would be the best to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [glCopyImageSubData](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyImageSubData.xhtml) and it seems to work fine. It's the only function that was able to do what I needed. It's a pity that it requires OpenGL 4.3.